# HTML5 polygon mouse over

Tags: html, mouse, polygons

I have a single HTML5 canvas. I have drawn 100+ dynamic polygons. These polygons are a collection of paths (beginPath, moveto, lineTo, ..., closePath).

Each of the polygons is stored in an array. I store the cocordinatesand some attribute info in each element.

I have drawn the polygons and all is well. I would now like to have a mouse over to display some of the attributes when I hover over the polygons.

Now I know I can not attach an event to any of the polygon objects as they arent really objects.

What is the most popular/fastest way of checking which polygon I am hovering over.

Note: I want to use pure HTML5, no kinetic or any other libs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will admit my bias upfront, because I wrote it, but you could use [alphapun.ch](http://alphapun.ch) to draw the polygons using actual elements, instead of (or in addition to) the canvas. That way you could properly detect events.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique is a two pass:

for each polygon in your array:

- Save the "bounding rectangle" along with each polygon info, and test if mouse cursor is inside that rectangle
- If the first test is positive, apply the "point inside polygon" algorithm, which is more costly.

Here is an example of that algorithm:

```
function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
  for (var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
  ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
  && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
  && (c = !c);
  return c;
}
```